# How to remove first index in array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

for example this is my array of arrays:

```
const arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]];
```

How can I remove the first index, so I get the array of arrays, but excluding the first index?

So `filteredArr = [[6, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]];` would be final output.

Thanks.

**NOTE: I don't want to mutate array.**

Comment: Note that `shift()` mutates the array rather than returning a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get a **new** array, and not mutate the original array.

Options 1: Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) with [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable) to get a new array with all items, but the 1st:

```js
const arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]];
const [, ...filteredArr] = arr;

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Option 2 : use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get all items after the 1st (index 0):

```js
const arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]];
const filteredArr = arr.slice(1);

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Comment: Great, I don't want to mutate array. Thanks!